# Eclipse Projects not loading in my Package explorer?

Tags: android

i was developing Android applications on my macbook pro after which i had to shift to the iMac at work. So i copied my Eclipse directory and the android sdk and the workspace and pasted it on the iMac at work.
I have set the Android sdk root inside the preferences of the Eclipse but the workspace is not loading inside my package explorer?

i have made the workspace folder inside the documents folder where it was in my macbook pro.

When Eclipse starts i choose the specified path of my workspace and then start eclipse.
Why are my workspace projects not being available in my package explorer?

thank you in advance.

EDIT:
i imported the project into my workspace. But there was .classpath 5.0 compatibility error, so i right clicked on my project and clicked android tools -> fix project properties. That error regarding .class path compatibility went away but a new error came in which the whole src folder inside my project has errors.. i mean each and every class.
And the error is regarding classes that come in the Android library...for eg. it is giving me error in the getCount method saying there is no such method in a class i used to extend the BaseAdapter class..what is going wrong here?
i have cleaned my project several times, but no change.

Comment: try `import existing project in workspace` option.

Comment: but the project is already in my workspace folder... why do i need to import it again?

Comment: Tried this, didn't recognize anything

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced something similar - had to create a new workspace and import the projects from my previous workspace to make it work. Pretty annoying, but it seems to be a bug in Eclipse.

Comment: Why would this be a bug?  Other folders can be present in the workspace that are not Eclipse projects.  It makes sense that you have to explicitly tell Eclipse which directories to pay attention to.

Comment: Err, I'm guessing it's a bug because it wasn't working when I posted this answer, but it seems to be working now.

Comment: So true Michell... unfortunately, I deleted the project from my package explorer . when i tried again to import the same project... its not doing anything after clicking finish button in Import existing apps

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the build path of the project links correctly to the Android SDK.  Right click on the project and choose configure build path and make sure that there are no red marks there.

Answer (score 1):

Your project list is stored at .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\projects\, so you might want check that file to see if your projects are there.
from : [Eclipse - No project visible in explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460449/eclipse-no-project-visible-in-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is i went to the package explorer and on the right site click the menu i.e. go to Filters -> Non  Shared Projects. Remove that check mark. Then i see all projects.