# Eclipse - No project visible in explorer

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using `Eclipse Helios 3.6.2` for android development. Today when I opened eclipse these is no projects visible in `package explorer.` Even though projects folders are present in directory. What can be reason for it? Is it missing some config file. How to make all projects in workspace visible again in explorer of eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: Is your workspace same which you use daily?

Comment: Yes I have checked that. It is same workspace.

Comment: @anujprashar: Could be an eclipse bug.. Did you try restarting Eclipse as well as your system?

Comment: @Ghost Yes I have tried restarting eclipse and also my system but still explorer is empty.

Comment: @anujprashar: This is weird..

Comment: In my case, I mistakenly selected the project directory as workspace. Selecting the parent directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Your project list is stored at:

```
`<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\`
```

So you might want check that file to see if your projects are there.
Sometimes selecting Top Level Elements -> Projects reveals additional projects that haven't been assigned a working set.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes projects are there in that folder.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this error! Just go to File->import and browse to your workspace directory as root directory of existing project and click finish. This will load all your projects in the selected directory i,e: workspace in this case to the package explorer  :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know the workspace path. When you open the eclipse first time It will ask path for workspace. If you know that go to that folder and check whether all the project that you have created are their if it's all their then just Import all the project. I think you change the workspace path that's why.

Comment: I didnt change workspace path and I have checked path it is same as I was using.

Answer (score 1):

Open Eclipse IDE

Click To File > Switch Workspace >Select Previous Workspace from List

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my Package Explorer view. Turns out the view looks different in debug perspective and normal perspective:

### Debug perspective (no projects visible)

[image]

### Ordinary Java perspective (projects visible)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to File
2. Import
3. select general or type of projects you wish to load
4. browse your work space
5. select all the projects
6. click FINISH
   and you are done

Answer (score 0):

1. go to window
2. show view
3. project explorer
4. double click on them

Answer (score 0):

None of these helped, the correct method for me was:

file -> import ->general ->existing projects into workspace-> coose your directory with projects in "select root directory" ; click finish and you've it there!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to do

1. File > Import
2. Maven > Existing Maven Projects
3. Press Next
4. Select Root Directory, select desired project and press "Finish"

I am guessing, since the Project was Maven, it had to be imported as its type.